# Camel KeyStore configuration, issue to read .jks file from classpath

Tags: java, spring-security, apache-camel, ssl-certificate

Using Camel version : 2.17.1

```
<camel:sslContextParameters
      id="sslContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers
        keyPassword="pass123">
      <camel:keyStore
          resource="KeyStore.jks"
          password="pass123"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>
  </camel:sslContextParameters>
```

I am getting the below exception on load :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: KeyStore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Is it the nature, or is there any workaround ?

More Trace:

```html
 Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.spring.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:458)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: KeyStore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1690)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:138)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:213)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:153)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
 at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:390)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:86)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: KeyStore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
 at org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:309)
 at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpsServerHelper.start(HttpsServerHelper.java:92)
 at org.restlet.Server.start(Server.java:579)
 at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent.addServerIfNecessary(RestletComponent.java:388)
 at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent.connect(RestletComponent.java:174)
 at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletEndpoint.connect(RestletEndpoint.java:116)
 at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletConsumer.doStart(RestletConsumer.java:112)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3269)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3563)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3499)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3429)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3197)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3053)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
 at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270)
 at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
 ... 21 more
```

Comment: No one to answer ?

Comment: FileNotFound means exactly "File Not found". Where is your KeyStore.jks actually located?

Comment: @Vadim when we "TRACE" we can find that the file is being read twice, file is in classpath. So if it can read without error first time, why it should give an exception second time. Are they missing to close the stream or something like that ?

Comment: Does not matter how many times file read from other places. There is an exact place when Camel component tries to open that file and cannot find it. Again where is your file? is it file system, in class path, packaged into jar or war? Because what you told Camel just that "file is in current directory". Is it there?

Comment: @Vadim like I mentioned, its in classpath.

Comment: Did you try Spring notation as classpath:KeyStore.jks ?

Comment: @Vadim yes, that is not identifying the file in first step itself. Have to mention that, giving this folder, it aims the class path itself from TRACE

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but when resource opens from class path it cannot raise a FileNotFound exception. It can be raised when  java.io.File  or FileInputStream in use. But from class path ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream is in use and when resource is not found it is just a null. Your exception shows that `org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory` class tries to open a file from File System, not from class path. It uses FileInputStream

Comment: What I can suggest: just for test put another copy of your KeyStore file in file system and give Camel an absolute path to it. Then see will it work or not.

Comment: That would may be do it, but keeping a copy also has to be dynamic enough, not like a hardpath to read the file. Can it go for an issue in Camel ?

Comment: You are right, but it can be first step just for test. Then you may find a way to make it as needed. I do not consider that it is an issue, maybe lack of ability to use classpath location... `org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory` definitely is not a part of Camel and if it cannot get Keystore from classpath, Camel cannot handle that. You have to follow what `org.restlet.engine.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory` requires. Still, what I possibly do is try to use `classpath:KeyStore.jks` first, then try to use absolute path, then ... think what to do next... :-)

Comment: @Vadim its not the way, still it brings in same case, file is not reading

Comment: @peaceUser  :Were you ever able to solve this?